# NeoVim takes two second to quit via ctrl + q key bind

Tags: linux, vim, neovim

I'm using following config in `.vimrc`. `Ctrl + q` key bind takes 2 seconds to quit `vim`.

```
" swap Escape and Caps Lock
au VimEnter * silent !xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Escape'   
au VimLeave * silent !xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Caps_Lock'

" Ctrl + q to quit
nmap <c-q> :q<CR>
imap <c-q> <Esc>:q<CR>
```

If silent is removed from the `VimLeave` event, following message is displayed (when `Ctrl + q` is pressed) and vim will quit automatically after 2 seconds.

```
:!xmodmap -e 'clear Lock'-e 'keycode 0x42 = Caps_Lock
xmodmap: please release the following keys within 2 seconds:

(keysym ex71, keycode 24)
Control L (keysym Oxffe3, keycode 37)
```

However, with above configurations, running the command manually (`:q` and hit enter) quit `vim` instantly.

Edit:
Default key bind `shift + zz` takes two seconds too.

```
$ nvim -version
> NVIM v0.3.4
```

Comment: So it's not vim. xmodmap gets angry and delays two seconds whenever you run it with a modifier key held down. You're scripting it to run on vim exit, so whenever you exit vim using a keybinding that involves a modifier... problems. I don't have a solution, however.

Comment: Yeah. I can recreate in a terminal by executing same command while pressing a key

Answer (score 2):

This looks to be a perpetually unsolved problem with X and xmodmap, and not with vim. If you search for "please release the following keys" you will find years of people complaining about the same thing with no solution except to remove `xmodmap` commands from places like bashrc and vimrc. When xmodmap is run in a way that alters modifiers, and any modifier is held down, it will complain and delay in this fashion. It does so because the underlying request to the X server *fails* whenever a modifier is held down, and it's waiting for you to release the key before it retries. So there's no easy solutions here. The only workarounds that come to mind are:

- Forget about the key remapping, don't run `xmodmap` on vim exit.
- Don't exit vim using keybindings that involve modifier keys.
- (Maybe) add a delay in the `VimLeave` command which is long enough for you to get your finger off of the key, but shorter than 2 seconds. This would reduce the inconvenience a bit, but wouldn't make it go away.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to just put the command in the background by adding an `&`.

Here it is:

```
au VimEnter * silent! !xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Escape' &
au VimLeave * silent! !xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Caps_Lock' &
```

You will still see the message in the terminal but vim exits instantly. If you do not want so see that message use this instead:

```
au VimEnter * silent! !xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Escape' 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
au VimLeave * silent! !xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Caps_Lock' 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

It redirects the standard output and the error output of xmodmap to `/dev/null`, so it is discarded and will not be shown.

It works in both vim and neovim.